# clone element and remove id

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my html

```
<table id="itable">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        ......
        ......
    </tr>
    <tr class="form">
        <td>Form Of Document<span class='start'>*</span></td>
        <td><select class='formDoc form-control required'><option value=''>--plz choose--</option></select> </td>
        <td>Number of document<span class='start'>*</span></td>
        <td><input type='text' value=''  class='numOfDoc num_only form-control required' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form">
        <td>Type of document<span class='start'>*</span></td>
        <td><input type='radio' name='docType' class='hard' value='1' checked />Hard-Copy
            <input type='radio' name='docType' id='soft' value='0'/>Soft-Copy</td>
        <td colspan='2'><center class='textAdd'>Add more<span id="addFormDoc" class='symbleAdd glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></center></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

this is my js

```
 $("#addFormDoc").on("click",function(){
  var tr = $("#itable").find('tr.form').clone();
  $("#itable tbody").append(tr);
});
```

*** my problem:
    - new element, I want remove class `.symbleAdd` and add class `.sysbleDelect`
    - new element, I want remove class `.form` because it's should copy(clone) from first(old) element only 
    - new element and old element of `hard-copy` and `soft-copy` can choose only one because it's have the same name, so how i can change name of it?

Comment: Use `.attr('id', newvalue).removeClass('form')` on the cloned element? Note, it is usually better to clone a hidden template element and not a live element, so you can start with a blank slate.

Comment: `tr.removeClass('form').find('#addFormDoc').attr('id', 'xyz');` add this line before append.

Comment: You have `tr` object, perform desired operation as `tr.removeClass('form')`

Comment: @Jai , thanks, it's work

Comment: @skjulikaka just added as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put this line just before `.append()` operation.

```
tr.removeClass('form') // <-------------------------removes the class from the tr
  .find('#addFormDoc').attr('id', 'specificId'); //<--updates the ID to new one.
```